# Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra and $V$ a completely reducible $A$-module. Show that the algebra $A_V$ is semisimple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory

This is Problem 1.6 from I.M. Isaacs, *Character Theory of Finite Groups*:

> Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra and $V$ a completely reducible (left) $A$-module which is also finite-dimensional as a vector space over $k$. Show that the algebra $A_V$ is semisimple.

Note: $A_V$ denotes the image of the algebra homomorphism $A \to \operatorname{End}_F(V)$, $a \mapsto a_V$, where $a_V$ is the natural action by multiplicating $a$ on the left: $a_V: V \to V, x \mapsto ax$. Also, by semisimple I mean $A_V$ is completely reducible as a left module over itself.

I think it could be proved using Jacobson radical. What I want to ask is whether the proposition can be proved in a more **direct** way,  **without** the help of Jacobson radical. Can anyone help?

**My 'proof'**:

Lemma: Let $M_1$, $M_2$ be finite-dimensional simple modules over $A$, $m_1\in M_1$, $m_2\in M_2$, $m_1, m_2 \neq 0$. Either $\operatorname{Ann}(m_1) = \operatorname{Ann}(m_2)$, or $\operatorname{Ann}(m_1) + \operatorname{Ann}(m_2) = A$.

Proof of lemma: $A/\operatorname{Ann}(m_i) \cong M_i$ and $M_i$ simple imply that $\operatorname{Ann}(m_i)$'s are maximal ideals of $A$. Thus, if $\operatorname{Ann}(m_1) \neq \operatorname{Ann}(m_2)$, there must be $\operatorname{Ann}(m_1) \subset \operatorname{Ann}(m_1) + \operatorname{Ann}(m_2)$, hence $\operatorname{Ann}(m_1) + \operatorname{Ann}(m_2) = A$.

Return to the original problem.

Suppose $V=V_1\oplus\dots\oplus V_n$, with $V_i$'s irreducible. Then
$$\operatorname{Ann}(V) = \bigcap_{i=1}^n\operatorname{Ann}(V_i) = \bigcap_{i=1}^n \bigcap_{v\in V_i, v \neq 0}\operatorname{Ann}(v).$$

Now partition $\bigcup_{i = 1} ^n V_i$ with respect to equivalence relation ~, where $v$~$w$ iff $\operatorname{Ann}(v) = \operatorname{Ann}(w)$, and let $\mathscr{V} = \{v_j: j \in J\}$ be a representative set. Then $\operatorname{Ann}(V) = \bigcap_{j\in J} \operatorname{Ann}(V_j)$. **If we had shown that $J$ is finite**, by the lemma Chinese Remainder Theorem applies, showing that $$A_V \cong A/\operatorname{Ann}(V) \cong \bigoplus_{j\in J} (A/\operatorname{Ann}(v_j)),$$ completing the proof.

Note that the proof relies on the hypothesis that the representative set $\mathscr{V}$ is finite, which I believe is true but cannot prove. In particular, it suffices to prove that the set $\{\operatorname{Ann}(m):m\in M\}$ is finite for a simple $A$-module $M$.

*edited under rschwieb's suggestion:*

$A/\operatorname{Ann}(v)$'is generally not a ring, so CRT does not hold in the full sense that the mapping is onto, as is pointed out by rschwieb. Still, one may proceed using the injection $\phi: A/\operatorname{Ann}(V) \to \bigoplus_{j\in J} (A/\operatorname{Ann}(v_j))$ if $J$ can be chosen to be **finite**. $\operatorname{Im} \pi_j \phi$ is a submodule of $A/\operatorname{Ann}(v_j)$, hence must be either $0$ or a simple module ($\pi_j$ is projection of the sum into $A/\operatorname{Ann}(v_j)$). It follows that the sum is semisimple.

But to chose a finite $J$ one has to use a complicated device (see rschwieb's comment below), which makes this proof way more complicated than that using $J(A)$.

Comment: @rschwieb I have edited the question to illustrate what $A_V$ is; I forgot it is not a standard notation because the book used it repeatedly. Also, by semisimple I mean the $A_V$ is completely reducible as a left module over itself. Thank you for pointing out the mistakes.

Comment: @rschwieb I have mentioned in my last reply that, by semisimple I mean $A_V$ is completely reducible as a left module over itself.

Comment: Yes, I meant for you to add it to the post as context.  Thank you for doing that.

Answer (score 2):

(Note: after this answer was given, the user inserted the "finite dimensional assumption.)

If semisimple means "is completely reducible as a left module over itself" then this claim is not correct as stated.

For example, Let $A=\prod_{i=0}^\infty F$ for a field $F$.  It has a semisimple submodule $V=\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty F$ which is faithful. Faithfulness means that the map $A\to A_V$ will be injective, hence an isomorphism.  But $A$ is not Artinian, so it cannot be completely reducible as a left module over itself.

If semisimple were taken to mean "has trivial Jacobson radical" then the claim is correct:  since $A_V\cong A/ann(V)$, we'd have that $V$ is a faithful semisimple $A_V$ module, which is the same thing as having trivial Jacobson radical.

Perhaps there is some assumption in the book that you've not included which would rectify the situation.

---

*Added after finite dimensionality was introduced*

If one assumes additionally that $V$ is finite dimensional, then also $End_F(V)$ and $A_V$ will also be finite dimensional.  Thus $A_V$ would be Artinian with Jacobson radical zero, i.e. a semisimple ring.

I am thinking to see if one can do this without utilizing the radical but at this point it seems like the simplest route...

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Please forgive me for my carelessness, because I do neglect two assumptions in the book. In the book (which is about character theory of **finite** groups), $A$ is assumed to be a **finite-dimensional** $k$-algebra, and $V$ is also **finite-dimensional** viewed as a vector space over the field $k$.

Comment: @zyy In general it is very bad form to "move the goalposts" on a question after it has been answered.  I will overlook it this time but in the future you should be very careful when posting not to omit hypotheses like this.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have only come across topics like 'semisimplicity' and 'algebra' in the context of representation theory of finite groups, but have never learnt them in their full generality. I should be more careful in the future.

Comment: I agree that the simplest route is to use the radical. But I have come across another text which proposes this problem **before** introducing the radical. So I wonder whether there is an alternative proof.

Comment: @zyy I see: thank you for sharing the context.  That is a good motivation.  If I think of anything I'll expand the answer further.

Comment: In the description of the problem, I have write down a 'proof' based on Chinese Remainder Theorem which I think might succeed. But the 'proof' relies on the hypothesis (which I also think is true) that there are only finitely unequal $\operatorname{Ann}(v)$, $v \in V$ for a simple module $V$. But I have not figured out how to prove the hypothesis. Could you please have a look?

Comment: In your example, $x$ and $y$ both generate a reducible module, while in the lemma I assume they should be picked from simple modules, hence generating simple modules.

Comment: @zyy I see, I must have overlooked that.  Part of the reason for doubt is that [there isn't really a CRT for _modules_](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3006687/29335https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3006687/29335) at least, not in the full sense that the mapping is onto.  But yes, I agree the annihilators are comaximal right ideals when the points are taken from simple modules.

Comment: @zyy You should take a look at [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43737136) which IIRC will allow you to extract a finite subset whose annihilators intersect to $ann(V)$.  Although this is now way way more complicated than just using $J(A)$ :)

Comment: I find that your link 'there isn't really a CRT for modules' is no longer valid. But still, I think the proof still works, assuming that 'CRT' for left ideals perserves most properties of the ordinary CRT except the surjectivity. That is because all modules on the right are simple, which implies that the images must be either $\{0\}$ or the full simple module. One might just delete the $\{0\}$'s, still getting a decomposition into simple modules.

Comment: You are right that $J(A)$ is the most straightforward way, especially if the finiteness requires such a complicated proof.

Comment: @zyy The proof still works if the product is finite, because then the product is semsimple, and so is the image of your injection. But really the key point of the CRT is surjectivity.  We always have the diagonal injection into the product.

Comment: @zyy For whatever the reason, my keyboard sometimes doubles something on the clipboard: [this link should work](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3006687/29335)

Comment: The link works now. Thank you for your patience. I have edited the problem according to your suggestion.